# PEP484 typing -- how to annotate Callable with NoReturn type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Is it possible to annotate `Callable` with the `NoReturn` type?

The way I would expect to do this yields an error:

```
from sys import exit
from typing import Callable, NoReturn

f: Callable[..., NoReturn] = exit
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 755, in __getitem__
>     return self.__getitem_inner__(params)
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 251, in inner
>     return func(*args, **kwds)
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 774, in __getitem_inner__
>     result = _type_check(result, msg)
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 135, in _type_check
>     raise TypeError(f"Plain {arg} is not valid as type argument")
> TypeError: Plain typing.NoReturn is not valid as type argument
> ```

Edit: for anyone who encounters this problem in the future, the issue was a bug in Python 3.7.0 and upgrading to Python 3.7.2 mitigates the issue.

Comment: This may be related to [Python issue 34921](https://bugs.python.org/issue34921), fixed in Python 3.7.2. The reproducing case in the issue is different, but the underlying cause may be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me (with Python 3.7.2) it works without an error:

```
>>> from sys import exit
>>> from typing import Callable, NoReturn
>>> f: Callable[..., NoReturn] = exit
>>>
```

Comment: Does mypy handle it correctly? I see that the questioner's error message came from trying to run the code, not trying to run mypy on the code, but mypy handling is also important.

Comment: mypy correctly doesn't complain about this in my case.

Comment: Upgraded 3.7.0 -> 3.7.2 and it works now! Brilliant